# saving image file from other site, with javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've done it before on PHP, but now i need do this on javascript. As far as i know, ajax works with only yourself hosts..

Comment: Saving the image where? You can't store files with JavaScript at the client.

Comment: with help of localstorage(html5)

Comment: @user635443: I would not call this storing a file. How about clarifying your question?

Comment: okay. just want to create a little image-parser on the only javascript. As a desktop programm. it is possble?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to to this (cross-domain) is with the help of a server script. Why don't you just send POST data to your server-script, and have that script read and save the off-site image.

Comment: I've done so before, but I was wondering to try to do so without resorting to other scripts.